# Calling an action method through ajax call is behaving unexpectedly

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, struts2

I have an action method given below-

```
public String getCommissionaryOfficeByCustomLocation() {
    Connection conn = null;

    try {
        ApplicantDbMethods db = new ApplicantDbMethods();
        conn = db.getConnection();
        commissionaryOffice = db.getCommissionaryOffice(conn, selectedCustomLocation);
        return SUCCESS;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return ERROR;
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ApplicantRegistrationDetails.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling this method via Ajax on dropdown's `onChange` event. After calling this action through Ajax when i run the application on debug mode I see that after executing the action method, this action method is called again and after this another action method is called automatically. this another method is-

```
public String getContactPersonForFutureCommunications() {
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
        if (session == null) {
            return ERROR;
        }
        String applicantId = session.get("ApplicantId").toString();
        if (applicantId == null) {
            return ERROR;
        }
        ApplicantDbMethods db = new ApplicantDbMethods();
        conn = db.getConnection();
        // db.insertFutureContactPerson(conn,applicantId,futureContact);
        if ("Other".equals(futureContact)) {
            return "OTHER";
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return ERROR;
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ApplicantRegistrationDetails.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

both action methods are in same action class.
 the jQuery method is called only once `onChange` event.The jQuery method is-

```
function getCommissionaryOffice(customLocation) {
    var location = $('#' + customLocation).val();
    $.ajax(
            {
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'getCommissionaryOffice',
                data: {selectedCustomLocation: location},
                //async: false ,
                success: function(data) {
                    var commissionaryOffice=data.commissionaryOffice;
                    $('#commissionaryOffice').val(commissionaryOffice);
                },
                error:function(data){
                    alert("error getting commissionay office!");
                }
            });

}
```

I don't know why it is happening please help.
the entries in `struts.xml` are given below-

```
<package name="default" extends="json-default">
    <result-types>
        <result-type name="tiles"
                     class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
    </result-types>

    <action name="getCommissionaryOffice" class="applicant.ApplicantRegistrationDetails" method="getCommissionaryOfficeByCustomLocation">
        <result name="success" type="json"/>
    </action>

    <action name="FutureContactPerson" class="applicant.ApplicantRegistrationDetails" method="getContactPersonForFutureCommunications">
         <result name="input" type="tiles">FutureContactDetails</result>
        <result name="success" type="tiles">SuccessfullySubmitted</result>

    </action>
 </package>
```

Comment: It is because your methods names begin with a `get`, the json result tries to serialize them.

Comment: @AleksandrM yes the problem is resolved but can you please elaborate this behavoiur.

Comment: it might be useful for others also

Comment: There is nothing to elaborate. Read the docs: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/json-plugin.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All methods in the action class that have `get` prefix comply to the [JavaBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans) convention and could be used as properties of the action bean. This is also called a *getter*.

The action configuration doesn't have any restrictions to map an action to a method with such name. When the action is called the method is executed, and you have mistaken thinking that the action is called twice.

Methods used as a getter in the action class could be called to access the property. It can be [OGNL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/), [JSON](http://json.org) or any other code using [`BeanInfo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/BeanInfo.html) to access properties and call a getter method. Better not to name methods mapped to the action with a getter to not confuse developers.